# Voice Interactor always returns null during Runtime

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, voice-recognition, voice, google-codelab

I am trying to implement the Voice Interactor in my project and the main idea to use this is, user will invoke a particular functionality by saying a word (like similar to 'Ok Google') and then application will navigate or act accordingly. I went to few tutorials and found this piece of code but when I try to implement, I throws Runtime Exception. Please find my code snippet below and appreciated your help.

**Manifest File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name="com.ivy.ivyvoicebot.MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.ivy.ivyvoicebot.MY_ACTION_INTENT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.VOICE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.media.action.STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.VOICE"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.actions.SEARCH_ACTION"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.VOICE"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="com.google.android.voicesearch.SELF_NOTE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        startVoiceTrigger();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Device not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private void startVoiceTrigger() {

    VoiceInteractor.PickOptionRequest.Option option1 = new VoiceInteractor.PickOptionRequest.Option("cheese", 1);
    option1.addSynonym("ready");
    option1.addSynonym("go");
    option1.addSynonym("take it");
    option1.addSynonym("ok");

    VoiceInteractor.Prompt prompt = new VoiceInteractor.Prompt("Say Cheese");
    VoiceInteractor voiceInteractor = getVoiceInteractor();
    voiceInteractor.submitRequest(new VoiceInteractor.PickOptionRequest(prompt,
                new VoiceInteractor.PickOptionRequest.Option[]{option1}, null) {
            @Override
            public void onPickOptionResult(boolean finished, Option[] selections, Bundle result) {
                if (finished && selections.length == 1) {
                    Message message = Message.obtain();
                    message.obj = result;
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Navigate To next screen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    getActivity().finish();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Didn't work", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                getActivity().finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Error Message:**

```
2020-06-19 17:02:51.633 23588-23588/com.ivy.ivyvoicebot E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.ivy.ivyvoicebot, PID: 23588
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ivy.ivyvoicebot/com.ivy.ivyvoicebot.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.app.VoiceInteractor.submitRequest(android.app.VoiceInteractor$Request)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3375)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3514)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2110)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7697)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.app.VoiceInteractor.submitRequest(android.app.VoiceInteractor$Request)' on a null object reference
    at com.ivy.ivyvoicebot.MainActivity.startVoiceTrigger(MainActivity.java:259)
    at com.ivy.ivyvoicebot.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:85)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7815)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7804)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1325)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3514) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2110) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7697) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950) 
2020-06-19 17:02:51.640 23588-23588/com.ivy.ivyvoicebot I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 23588 SIG: 9
```

**Reference Links:**

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/voice-interaction/index.html?index=..%2F..index#6

https://hub.packtpub.com/voice-interaction-and-android-marshmallow/

https://www.mobindustry.net/how-to-implement-voice-interactions-into-your-android-app/

Comment: The error is here, please update the question with the listings of the method involved in
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.app.VoiceInteractor.submitRequest(android.app.VoiceInteractor$Request)' on a null object reference

at com.ivy.ivyvoicebot.MainActivity.startVoiceTrigger(MainActivity.java:259)

the line 259

Comment: Hi! Did you find a solution for your problem?

Answer (score 0):

MainActivity must not be launched directly. It should be launched by VoicePrompt only that scenario the instance of the VoiceInteractor be available. Use isLocalVoiceInteractionSupported in Kotlin to check.